# How does server force browser to send request using IPv4 or IPv6? How does a server extract both my IPv4 and IPv6?

Tags: .net, http, networking, ipv6, ipv4

I would love to know the solution in a general HTTP way but if it's relevant, I usually use ASP.NET Core for web servers.

I noticed when I access [WhatIsMyIPAddress](https://whatismyipaddress.com/), it can show both my IPv4 and IPv6:

[image]

If I am using IPv6, it takes a while for IPv4 to show up and if I disable IPv6 from my network interface, it takes a while for IPv6 to say there is none. I check the Network and find out they find my IPv4 by sending another request to `https://whatismyipaddress.com/ds3?token=[sometoken]&v=4`. I tried tracing it down with a HTTP client but find nothing interest.

How do they force browser to send request using IPv6 or IPv4?

Answer (score 1):

They create a DNS record that only has an IPv4 address and a DNS record that only has an IPv6 address. Then they use JavaScript to load something (probably some JSON data showing the IP address that connected to the server) from both those hostnames and they see which ones succeed.

The resulting data is then displayed.

Comment: That's a good solution. But is there any other way? I notice in the request for IPv4 they are still using `whatismyipaddress.com` as the hostname which means their DNS records have both IPv4 and IPv6.